# Selenium Web Driver for Telegram Data Extraction with Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Hello everyone i wanna extract automated Telegram group chat messages, With Selenium I took care of it using the Telegram login section.I don't want to do this using the Telegram bot api.Login part succeeded with Selenium,after that can it be done using BeutifulSoup for data extraction?

All I want from you is to give information about what to do next? I want to make progress in my project by sharing your ideas, not writing code, but their status as soon as possible.

Login section down below

```
def login():
    print("Connecting to Telegram Web, please wait")

    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/usr/bin/geckodriver')


    browser.get("https://web.telegram.org/#/login")

    sleep(3)

    phone_input_code = browser.find_element_by_name("phone_country")
    phone_input_number = browser.find_element_by_name("phone_number")

    country_code = input("Country code: ")
    phone_number = input("Phone number: ")

    phone_input_code.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE + Keys.BACKSPACE + country_code + Keys.ENTER)
    phone_input_number.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE + phone_number + Keys.ENTER)

    # Wait for the page to load
    sleep(5)

    confirm_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/input")
    confirm_code = input("Confirmation code (sent via SMS): ")
    confirm_input.send_keys(confirm_code + Keys.ENTER)

    sleep(5)
    password_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input")
    password_send = input("Please Login Password:")
    password_input.send_keys(password_send + Keys.ENTER)
    return browser
```

In the Telegram Web interface opened after logging in, I examined how group messages appear in html, but I had a hard time.Could the HTML parse process provide a solution for us here? I was wondering about this, Can BeautifulSoup do the job? What functions will be used if Selenium can ?

I am waiting for your ideas and solution methods. Thank you very much in advance. (Please do not be offensive)

Answer (score 0):

basically, you need to initialize the bs4(BeautifulSoup) variable by taking the html from selenium i.e.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
```

and then, you can use the `soup` variable like follows:

```
if soup.find('li', class_="pagination-paginationMeta") is not None:
    pageCount = int(filterPageNumber(
    soup.find('li', class_="pagination-paginationMeta").text))
else:
    pageCount = 1
```

Look i have implemented a full-fleged scraper using Selenium, requests, bs4 for [Myntra](https://myntra.com) which you can checkout here [Github-Repo](https://github.com/BharatKJain/Myntra-Webscraping/blob/master/main/main.py)
(P.S. i haven't done proper documentation and the code is literally RAW, so it get be difficult to understand.)